# How can i get the seed value of an identity column in MySql

Tags: mysql, t-sql, identity, seed

To get the seed and step values of an identity column in sql server i can use this syntax

```
SELECT ColumnName = name, Seed = seed_value, Step = increment_value 
  FROM sys.identity_columns
```

So far in MySql i have found that if i use this syntax

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
 WHERE auto_increment IS NOT NULL
```

I can at least find out which columns are an identity...

The question being how can i get the SEED and STEP values of the identity column from the MySQL Schema.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the system wide settings using:

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'auto_inc%';
```

The result:

```
| Variable_name            | Value 
+--------------------------+-------
| auto_increment_increment | 1     
| auto_increment_offset    | 1
```

Reference:

- [auto_increment_increment](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication-options-master.html#sysvar_auto_increment_increment)
- [auto_increment_offset](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication-options-master.html#sysvar_auto_increment_offset)

The only AUTO_INCREMENT attribute you can control outside of this is the starting value, [using an ALTER TABLE statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html):

```
ALTER TABLE tbl AUTO_INCREMENT = 100;
```

Comment: So from what im gathering the auto_increment column on information_Schema.tables is actually the seed value and the "step" or "offset" can only be ++ or 1 unless changed to a special type of increment.

Comment: @mmcdonald: The defaults are for increment and offset are 1 - you can change them but it's instance wide, not per table or database.